# Kde neon dolphin keeps crashing

Tags: kde

so i did a fresh install of kde neon on my laptop and i did all the updates and when i open dolphin it keeps crashing every time i open it and when i went in the terminal and did

```
dolphin --new-window
```

i get this

```
kf.kio.widgets: Cannot read information about filesystem under path "/home/juston/.cache/thumbnails/"
kf.solid.frontend.devicemanager: Couldn't get StorageAccess for ""/home/juston/.cache/thumbnails/"" - File doesn't exist
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = dolphin path = /usr/bin pid = 3368
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/dolphin --new-window 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi

[1]+  Stopped                 dolphin --new-window
```

can i have some help please?
did i miss something when installing kde neon?

Answer (score 0):

I was also Having the same issue after the recent update, it seems there is a bug in the recent update.The solution i did for this is simply creating the directory which it says "Couldn't Get Storage Access" in your case below command Should Work.

```
mkdir -p /home/juston/.cache/thumbnails
```